# Diferença entre Usuários e Logins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

No SQL Server nós temos a opção de criar [logins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login) e [database users](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user).

Qual é a diferença entre os dois?

Answer (score 0):

Um Login dá acesso ao SERVIDOR (tipo localhost), já um user dá acesso a um BANCO DE DADOS

Um login pode estar associado a vários users.